# null last element in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, null

I have the following 2D array:

`private static Object[][] myClass = new Object[6][5];`

and I am looking to null the last element in the array (`myClass[lastIndex][all indexes] = null`) using the following code:

```
for(int y = 0;y < 5;y++) {
  myClass[5][y] = null;
}
```

However it seems to be deleting the last two elements in the array, what is causing this?

EDIT:

array print out before delete:

```
one
1
1
1
1.0
two
2
2
2
2.0
three
3
3
3
3.0
four
4
4
4
4.0
five
5
5
5
5.0
six
6
6
6
6.0
```

After "deleteing" element `one`(In practise I want to "delete" element one by copying all the elements down one index and setting the last to null):

```
two
2
2
2
2.0
three
3
3
3
3.0
four
4
4
4
4.0
five
5
5
5
5.0
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

My full delete code:

```
  public void deleteStudent(int studentChoice) {
    for(int i = studentChoice;i < myClass.length - 1;i++) {
      myClass[i] = myClass[i+1];
    }
    myClassCount = myClassCount - 1;
    for(int y = 0;y < 5;y++) {
      myClass[5][y] = null;
    }
  }
```

`int studentChoice` is the index of the array.
`myClassCount` is a variable that's incremented/de-incremented as elements are added/deletted

Comment: Should work fine...How are you verifying that it is indeed deleting that last two elements?

Comment: I am manually printing out the array as well as using the debug function in intellij Idea

Comment: Then it is not this code that is the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer to show the before and after print along with a bit more info

Comment: So the problem probably lies with the fact that you are 'copying down' wrong, not with this code.

Comment: I added the code I'm using to copy the array to the end of my post

Comment: @Colin747 - What are you trying to do ? Are you trying to do myClass[lastIndex][lastIndex] = null or myClass[lastIndex][all indexes] = null ?

Comment: myClass[lastIndex][all indexes] = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subtle problem:
When you copy down, the references are copied, not the values in the array so that in the last step, because you don't overwrite myClass[5], myClass[5] == myClass[4] so that any changes you then make to any element in myClass[5] are replicated in myClass[4] as they are the same object! Therefore when you null each object in myClass[5], you are nulling everything in myClass[4] aswell. This can be avoided by copying the individual values down, rather than just the arrays.

You can copy the values down like this:

```
for(int i = studentChoice;i < myClass.length - 1;i++) {
    for(int y = 0;y < 5;y ++){
        myClass[i][y] = myClass[i+1][y];
    }
}
```

As a side note, this behavior can be demonstrated by the following:

```
Object[] array1 = {1};
Object[] array2 = array1;
array2[0] = 2;
System.out.println(array1[0]);//Prints 2
```

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks! How would I go about coping the values down?

Comment: Thanks again, I see what you mean by it being a subtle problem. You've been a great help and an informative answer.